# Test class for current user and get set member variable?

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have following class:

```
public without sharing class exampleController{
    public static User currentUser {
        get {
            if(currentUser == null){
                currentUser = [SELECT Id,
                    Email,LastLoginDate,CompanyName,Contact.Name,Phone,City,State,PostalCode,CreatedDate,LanguageLocaleKey,
                    CustomerCareDownloadsCount__c, CustomerCareLoginCount__c, Contact.Language_EncodingKey__c,
                    ContactId,Contact.AccountId,Contact.Order_Visibility__c, Contact.Invoice_Visibility__c,Contact.eCommerce_Visibility__c, CustomerNo for SAP invoices webservices FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
            }

            return currentUser;
        }
        public set;
    }
}
```

How to cover currentUser in test class.I write test class but covered nothing.I wrote like below:

```
@isTest
public class TestexampleController {
static testmethod void exampleControllerTestMethod(){
                Account oAccount = new Account();
                oAccount.Name = 'MyRecords Controller Testing';
                oAccount.BillingCountry = 'USA';
                oAccount.SAP_Bill_To_Account_Number__c = '043343334';
                oAccount.SAP_Ship_To_Account__c = '043343335';
                insert oAccount;

                Contact oContact = new Contact();
                oContact.LastName = 'MyportaUser';
                oContact.AccountId = oAccount.Id;
                oContact.Status__c = 'Active';
                oContact.Order_Visibility__c = 'Yes';
                oContact.Invoice_Visibility__c = 'Yes';
                oContact.eCommerce_Visibility__c = 'Yes';
                insert oContact;

                Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='someProfile']; 
                User u = new User(Alias = 'storddt' ,Email='myportalOrderuser@testorg.com',CompanyName='saturn',Phone='0555444111',City='bang',State='bg',Country='USA',
                                  EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='OrderTesting', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                                  LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                                  TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='myportalordercommunity@testorg.com',ContactId=oContact.Id);
                insert u;
        System.runAs(u) {
        exampleController tm = new exampleController();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to access the member variables of main class from test class for them to get covered.

You can access the static variable using the below code

```
User currentUser = exampleController.currentUser;
```

So, your code will be

```
System.runAs(u) {
    exampleController tm = new exampleController();
    User currentUser = exampleController.currentUser;
}
```

**Note :** Make sure to write the assert statements in test class to verify if the functionality you have developed is working as expected or not.

Comment: Cool! now works good.Thanks.